# Jest test is throwing "TypeError:service(...).returns is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jestjs, graphql, nestjs, typeorm

The service is written in Nest.js TypeORM

```
  @EnableLog()
  public async assignUsersToContracts(
    id: string,
    contractUsers: ContractUserInput[],
    authUser: any,
  ): Promise<string> {
    const contract = await this.contractService.findOneOrFail({
      where: { id },
    });
    const statusEditable = this.contractService.getContractStatusEditable();
    if (!statusEditable.includes(contract.status)) {
      throw new GeneralApplicationException(
        'Users cannot be assigned at this stage',
      );
    }
    const assignUsers: ContractUser[] = [];
    if (contract.assignedUsers) {
      for (const item of contract.assignedUsers) {
        await this.contractUserRepo.softDelete(item.id);
      }
    }
    for (const contractUser of contractUsers) {
      const newUser = await this.userService.getOrCreate(
        { email: contractUser.email },
        {
          email: contractUser.email,
          firstName: contractUser.firstName,
        },
      );
      if (!newUser)
        throw new GeneralApplicationException(
          'Not able to share to the user for now',
        );
      assignUsers.push({
        userId: newUser.id,
        role: contractUser.role,
      } as CoUser);
    }
    await this.contractUserRepo.save(assignUsers);
    return 'Successfull';
  }
```

Its testing is done using Jest

```
describe('assignUsersToContracts', () => {
    it('should throw an error when contract is not editable ', async () => {
      try {
        contractRepo.findOne.mockResolvedValueOnce(newContract);
        contractService
          .findOneOrFail(Arg.any())
          .returns(Promise.resolve(newContract));
        contractService
          .getContractStatusEditable()
          .returns(await Promise.resolve(editContractStatus));
        await contractUserService.assignUsersToContracts(
          newContract.id,
          contractUserInputList,
          authUser,
        );
      } catch (error) {
        expect(error).toBeInstanceOf(GeneralApplicationException);
      }
    });
    it('should throw an error when a user is undefined ', async () => {
      try {
        contractRepo.findOne.mockResolvedValueOnce(newEditableContract);
        contractService
          .findOneOrFail(Arg.any())
          .returns(Promise.resolve(newEditableContract));
        contractService
          .getContractStatusEditable()
          .returns(await Promise.resolve(editContractStatus));
        contractUserRepository.softDelete.mockResolvedValueOnce(deleteResult);
        userService
          .getOrCreate(Arg.any(), Arg.any())
          .returns(Promise.resolve(undefined));
        await contractUserService.assignUsersToContracts(
          newEditableContract.id,
          contractUserInputList,
          authUser,
        );
      } catch (error) {
        expect(error).toBeInstanceOf(GeneralApplicationException);
      }
    });
    it('should save a user to a Contract', async () => {
      try {
        contractRepo.findOne.mockResolvedValueOnce(newEditableContract);
        contractService
          .findOneOrFail(Arg.any())
          .returns(Promise.resolve(newEditableContract));
        contractService
          .getContractStatusEditable()
          .returns(await Promise.resolve(editContractStatus));
        contractUserRepository.softDelete.mockResolvedValueOnce(deleteResult);
        userService
          .getOrCreate(Arg.any(), Arg.any())
          .returns(Promise.resolve(userResponse.user));
        contractUserRepository.save.mockResolvedValueOnce(userResponse);
        const res = await contractUserService.assignUsersToContracts(
          newContract.id,
          contractUserInputList,
          authUser,
        );
        expect(res).toEqual('Successfull');
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    });
  });
```

This throws error:

```
● Test ContractUserService › assignUsersToContracts › should throw an error when a user is undefined 

    expect(received).toBeInstanceOf(expected)

    Expected constructor: GeneralApplicationException
    Received constructor: TypeError

      315 |         );
      316 |       } catch (error) {
    > 317 |         expect(error).toBeInstanceOf(GeneralApplicationException);
          |                       ^
      318 |       }
      319 |     });
      320 |     it('should save a user to a Contract', async () => {

 console.log
    TypeError: contractService.getContractStatusEditable(...).returns is not a function
        at Object.<anonymous> (/t/service/contract.user.service.test.ts:328:12)
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)

  

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
```

Comment: What is that `.returns()` method? I've not seen that on Jest mocks before

Comment: These are the service function properties that available on mocking
{returns: OneArgumentRequiredFunction<type[], void>;
    throws: OneArgumentRequiredFunction<any, never>;}
if its wrong what should I use for mocking the service fuction

Comment: The cause of the error is that, in second it , the same value of contract is passing from the first it . So how to clear the constants value after a it

Comment: What are you using to create these mocks? I've not seen `jest.fn()` have a `.returns()` method

Comment: const contractService = Substitute.for<ContractService>();

Comment: What is your mocking library? That's not a standard `jest.fn()` mock, right?

Comment: yes jest.fn()  is used

Comment: @JayMcDoniel can you help me to  mock services from imported modules in nestjs using jest